# Properly handing failed snippet completions

Tags: emacs, elisp, yasnippet, advising-functions, defadvice

I use TAB to expand snippets from yasnippet, when it doesn't expand a snippet, it usually falls back to indenting (the default command bound to TAB), this is referred to by yasnippets custom variable `yas-fallback-behavior` which can only be `call-other-command` or `return-nil`.

The desired functionality I want is upon hitting TAB:

1. Tries to complete snippet, succeeds, or fails silently.
2. Checks if we're in PHP mode, and calls `php-complete-function`,
   succeeds, or fails silently.
3. Defaults to it's current indentation command
   (`indent-for-tab-command`).

It currently performs 1, then 3, perfectly. I was however, able to make it work for the most part by advising `yas--fallback` with this bit of code:

```
(defadvice yas--fallback (before try-php-expand (&optional arg from-trigger-key-p) activate)
  (when (string-equal mode-name "PHP")
    (php-complete-function)))
```

The only **main issue that remains** is that when trying to indent anything using TAB, `php-complete-function` does **not** fail silently, but instead spams the minibuffer with messages from it's multiple checks for a PHP completion.

So is there a way to disallow messaging from that function in this case, without doing all the same checks it does essentially re-programming the function in my advise? Alternatively, is there a better way to do this with yasnippet to begin with that I'm missing?

Comment: So this isn't really about `yas` but about `php-complete-function` right?

Comment: Not really, you could substitute `php-complete-function` with anything a user would want to do after a failed snippet completion. See the very last sentence of the question.

Comment: `(let (message-log-max) (message "foobar"))` seems to be the way to disable logging according to the manual, but it doesn't work for me on Emacs 24 or I misunderstand the purpose of this.

Comment: *facepalm* I was looking at the log of the thing that was returned.

Comment: @DanLaManna: Side remark, replace `(string-equal mode-name "PHP")` with `(derived-mode-p php-mode)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of logging in any expression by setting `message-log-max` to `nil`.

```
(defadvice yas--fallback (before try-php-expand (&optional arg from-trigger-key-p) activate)
  (when (string-equal mode-name "PHP")
    (let (message-log-max)
      (php-complete-function))))
```

Comment: This does stop it from logging to *Messages* but continues to display messages in the minibuffer, which is the main issue. I'm afraid I may need to adjust my advice to check all the checks `php-complete-function` does.

Comment: @DanLaManna You can minimize output to the echo area by setting `message-truncate-lines`. Please post a full solution if you have found it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like (guaranteed 100% untested):

```
(defvar my-inhibit-messages nil)
(defadvice message (around my-inhibit activate)
  (unless my-inhibit-messages ad-do-it))

(defadvice php-complete-function (around my-silence-php-messages activate)
  (let ((my-inhibit-messages t))
    ad-do-it))
```